# Javascript Files Loading With Errors in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, p5.js

I've recently started using Visual Studio 2019 and am trying to build a Javascript WebApp with NodeJS and p5. I'm not sure if there is a special procedure for this, but for some reason, the Javascript files linked to HTML page are outputting errors.

This is my Javascript file 'server.js'. It worked fine before I added the script to the HTML file, so I don't *think* this is the problem.

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 80;
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("File not found.");
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(port);
```

---

This is the HTML file with the script loaded in.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>~~ Tetris ~~</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

---

And this is a screenshot of the console output when I open the Firefox web server.

[image: this]

I'd really appreciate the help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The HTML file loads `sketch.js`, not `server.js`. Is that a typo in the question?

Comment: There are lots of duplicates of this, I'll try to find one. The core problem is that your server responds to **every** request with the contents of `index.html`. It fails to look at the URL the request is asking for and serve up different things based on it.

Comment: can you show us the code of the file sketch.js

Comment: because the error is in the file sketch.js we should see this file

Comment: @simon — No, it isn't. The error is that when the browser asks for sketch.js, the server gives it index.html. Please read the earlier comments.

Comment: `fs.readFile('./index.html'` always reads `index.html`, you need to get the filename from the URL parameter and read that file. Also, the Content-type header should be different depending on the file extension.

Comment: @Quentin sorry maybe I dont  explain me well I said that the error is when the server got a query from the server with the file  sketch.js and in the console said that there is a  error in expression  ffor this reason I thought there is the error.

Comment: Okaz, @Quentin , the question that duplicates mine has an answer, but I don't really understand how to implement that. How do I change the content-type based on what file it's loading? How do I give the server the .js file when it asks for it?

Comment: Use express. Use the static module. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Quentin , I'm having trouble figuring out how to effectively use Express.js in this manner. Is there any way we could communicate on any other platform for a 1 on 1 quick chat about how to implement it?

Comment: @LovelyLayne — It's covered by the (short) [Getting Started guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html). Just walk through the whole getting started guide.